# How to measure only the true RMS AC component of the waveform in an ADC?

Tags: voltage, ac, adc, rms, offset

I need to read an AC signal on an ADC. I have already conditioned the signal with an offset of 2.5V, which will vary from 0 to 5V.

How to calculate the Vac true RMD voltage of any signal (sinusoidal, square, triangular) and, when the AC signal is not added to the 2.5v offset, the result of the calculation must be 0?

I've tried to rectify the signal by processing the data from the adc and creating a virtual offset of 2.5 V, but I would not like to use a virtual vmed.

In short, what I need to calculate is only the true RMS AC component of the waveform, disregarding the DC.

Comment: What frequency is the waveform and how many harmonics do you wish to consider. You are sampling the waveform and so you have to trade off sampling speed against errors due to harmonic distortion. It's a compromise that also needs to take account of your CPU processing overhead.

Comment: variable frequency, from 100 to 200 Hz and two hamonics

Comment: ok, considering the correct sampling, is there an equation to obtain the correct result without having to rectify the data during reading?

Comment: Do you know the definition of RMS? Calculate that.

Comment: @LucasPercisi are you guessing about the harmonics? I think you might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decide on what window you want the AC RMS value over.

Determine the mean of the samples in the window.

For each sample, subtract the mean.  Square each sample and sum them together.

Divide the sum of the squares by the number of samples.  This is the mean squared value.

Take the square root of that result to obtain RMS.  Note that it will rarely be zero.  The mean will be close to zero, which is why we're using it as a reference value here to subtract the DC component.